# Arduino Invert byte

Tags: arduino, bit-manipulation, byte

I`m using a I2C i/o expander to read up to 8 inputs.

The i/o expander provide a 8 bit output.... 1 byte.
Because the e/o expander has internal pull-ups, all 8 bit are 1 when all port are not connected to GND.

> So the output is then  255 ... B11111111

when all port are connected to GND.. all 8 bit become 0.

> So the output then is  0 ... B00000000

All good, but I could like to invert the signals, when all port are not connected to GND the output should be: 0 ... B00000000.

And when all port are connected to GND the output should be 255 ... B11111111

The usage of Bitwise NOT does not really what i want.

from 255 to -1

Which is logical because they mentioned it on their website:

[Link](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/bitwise-operators/bitwisenot/)

The code I have does not really work...

```
byte OutputI2C;
byte OutputI2CInvert;
byte InputModbus;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Wire.requestFrom(B0111000, 1); //connect to i/o expander
    OutputI2C = Wire.read(); // Read data
    OutputI2CInvert = OutputI2C; // make copy
    delay(250);
    Serial.print(~OutputI2CInvert); // invert
}
```

So I hope someone know how to invert the byte without negative output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your type `byte` is unsigned, normally the bitwise not should work…
Can you try to cast your output to this type before printing?

Something like `Serial.print((byte) ~OutputI2CInvert);`

This should force Arduino not to consider the first bit as a sign bit.

Comment: I don't quite understand why this makes a difference. is the return value of ~byteValue not a byte? why else would the cast be necessary?

Comment: I think the return value of `~byteValue` is a byte but the `Serial.print` interprets its first bit as a sign bit. Thus, the value of `~byteValue` was correct, only the printing was wrong.

Comment: but if the return value of  `~byteValue` is a byte, how can `Serial.print` know that there was a cast to byte... it only sees the result of that cast.

Comment: `InputModbus = ((byte)~OutputI2C);` works, but `InputModbus = (~OutputI2C);` also works, maybe the `Serial.print` does something with the byte!?

Comment: @stefandekraker so it didn't make any difference for the Serial.print?

Comment: no no difference... well i`m happy you all helped me out so quick, towards the next problems

Answer (score 1):

Thank you that got it all working, with al litte bit of tweaking I`m uploading al the data to modbus.

```
#include <Mudbus.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

Mudbus Mb;
byte OutputI2C;
byte InputModbus;

void setup() {
    Wire.begin(); // start I2C bus
    uint8_t mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x00, 0x51, 0x06 }; // set MAC address 
    Ethernet.begin(mac); // start ethernet connection 
}

void loop() {
    Wire.requestFrom(B0111000, 1); //connect to i/o expander
    OutputI2C = Wire.read(); // Read data
    InputModbus = ((byte)~OutputI2C); // invert the data
    Mb.Run(); // start modbus connection
    Mb.R[0] = InputModbus; // insert inverted data from i/o expander
    delay(250); // small delay 
}
```